# ActiveRestClient respond to 204 No Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-rest-client

I have a `before_request` for all ActiveRestClient calls, but the server is responding with a 204 No Content on some actions. This causes an error:

```
MultiJson::LoadError in FilesController#update 795: unexpected token at ''
```

This is the `before_request`:

```
before_request do |name, request|
  request.headers["Accept"] = 'application/json'
  request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
end
```

How can I accept some responses to be no content when using ActiveRestClient?

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already committed a patch back to the project.  I fixed it a different way, I added after_filter functionality to match the existing before_filter functionality.  This allows you to change responses globally (if you have your own Base object), or for a specific response.  My PR is at:

https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client/pull/70

You can see an example of how to use it at my fork (because my push access has been revoked for some reason):

https://github.com/andyjeffries/active-rest-client#using-filters